# Summernote - How To Disable "Text To Display" When Adding A Link To An Image

Tags: javascript, summernote

I am using summernote and attempting to add an image inside of the note and then apply a link to said image.

As you will see in my image, all works well until I remove the "Text To Display" - I cannot "insert link" once I remove the "Text To Display" option.

Why in the world would it require "Text To Display" on an image? How do I fix this and/or just remove this "Text To Display" when linking an image...

My code:

```
$(".summernote").summernote({ ... });
```

Thanks

**Update:** Actually this issue is much deeper. Summernote cannot even hyperlink images. What?!?! Is this for real?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be the alt attribute.

Refer

> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp